# Is it possible to directly install a gem from a git repository?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

Using bundler, you can do something like this in the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'my_gem', :git => 'git@github:me/my_gem.git'
```

That builds the gem in that repo and installs it. Works great. Is it possible to do something similar just using the command-line gem tool? Something like this?

```
gem install my_gem --git="git@github:me/my_gem.git"
```

Obviously that command doesn't work, but is there something like it that does? I know I can clone the repo, run a `gem build my_gem.gemspec` and then a `gem install my_gem-1.2.3.gem`. But I'm wondering if there is a direct one-liner that hides these intermediate steps behind the scenes.

Comment: https://github.com/rdp/specific_install seems to do just this.

Answer (score 5):

Because unlike typical Git repositories, GitHub builds gems, if the project is hosted on GitHub and the gem is found in the [source list](http://gems.github.com/list.html) then you can add GitHub to your sources list like this:

```
$ gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
```

and then later install gems as desired in a single step, like this:

```
$ sudo gem install username-projectname
```

Otherwise, there's no one-step solution, and you'll have to do something like this:

1. download the gem zip/tar file
2. `gem build <gemname>.gemspec`
3. `sudo gem install <gemname>-x.x.x.gem`

Comment: my gem is not in the source list. it is a private repository.

Comment: and the latter solution i already know, as i outlined in my post. i was just wondering if there was a one-liner for the gem command. maybe there isn't.

Comment: You could write a shell function that you passed arguments to. But, I don't know of any slick one-liners.

Comment: http://gems.github.com/ says "We've stopped building gems, check out RubyGems.org.". I think this happened a year or two ago.

Comment: Maybe it would help for you to setup a private gem server?  http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/