# Gems not found by 'gem list' when using 'bundle install' for git gems with RVM

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I'm currently trying to run 'bundle install' to install a git based gem using a Gemfile and consequently use ruby/ other ruby commands without bundler with the latest version of RVM (1.14.3).

I believe the cause of the issue is that bundler is installing the git gem into .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@something/bundler/gems while all other gems are installed into .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@something/gems. As a result, 'bundle list' shows the gem but 'gem list' does not.

Any thoughts here? I'd really prefer not to use bundle to execute everything.

Answer (score 6):

Bundler is for bundling gems with applications. It doesn't make sense to use it for system gems. Unfortunately, the non-bundler gem system offers no direct way to install git-based gems (I actually asked a question about this previously, see [Is it possible to directly install a gem from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815436/is-it-possible-to-directly-install-a-gem-from-a-git-repository)). Instead, you have to do it manually in three steps:

1. Clone the gem repo (this is assuming a github repository, but it will work for a repository hosted anywhere, just substitute the right git repo location).

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/user/gem.git
   ```
2. Go to the cloned gem repo directory and build the gem (this will also check for dependencies and warn you if the install failed because of a missing dependency -- in that case just install the dependencies and try again).

   ```
   rake gem
   ```

   Or if that doesn't work:

   ```
   gem build gem.gemspec
   ```
3. This should have created a file with a name like `pkg/gem-1.2.3.gem` (sometimes it will build in the `pkg` directory like this, sometimes it will build in the gem repo root directory). You can now install it.

   ```
   gem install pkg/gem-1.2.3.gem
   ```

Comment: I guess this ticket is related https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler/issues/21

Comment: I did more research and found the comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175511/why-is-bundler-not-installing-gems-stored-in-get-repo-properly which references http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/12/some-of-the-problems-bundler-solves/ -- I recognize that gem and bundler are different but I'm really looking for way to make the gem/ bundler/gem dirs be the same dirs so gem can just use the bundler installed git gems?